# how to enable browser-based tinymce spellchecker

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am dealing with a tinymce version 3.9.3.

For some reason the browser spellchecker doesn't work.

I tried using also the setup attribute but when I enabled it I lost all the styles.

This is my code:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        
        /*setup : function(ed) {
            ed.on('init', function(evt) {
              ed.getBody().setAttribute('spellcheck', true); 
            });
        },*/
        
        language : "<?=$_SESSION['interface_lang'];?>",
        valid_elements : '*[*]',
        forced_root_block: false ,
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins: "style,table,template",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "formatselect,fontsizeselect,styleselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,cut,copy,paste,undo,redo,link,unlink,template",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,image,hr,|,tablecontrols",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",
        content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "/js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "/js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "/js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "/js/media_list.js",
            
        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "xxx",
            staffid : "xxx"
        },
        
        template_templates : [
            {
                title : "Template",
                src : "request_templ/tbl_detail3.html",
                description : "Approfondimenti"
            },
        ]
    });
```

Have you some ideas why it doesn't work? Can help?

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe I am a quick learner.

I solved using the following property:

```
gecko_spellcheck: true
```